# How to tokenize/parse data in an excel sheet using spacy

Tags: excel, nlp, spacy, doc

I'm trying to convert an excel sheet into a doc object using spacy, I spent the last couple of days trying to go around it but it seems a bit challenging.  I have opened the sheet in both openpyxl and pandas, I can read the excel sheet and output the content but I couldn't integrate spacy to create doc/token objects.

Is it possible to process excel sheets in spacy's pipeline?

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to get the text into a plain string and then pass the string to spaCy. spaCy doesn't know anything about Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacy has no support for excel.
You could use pandas to read either the csv(if csv format)
or excel file
like

```
     import pandas as pd
     df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

or

```
     df  = pd.read_excel(file)
```

respectively.
Select required text column and iterate over  df 'column' values and pass them over to nlp() of spacy